# Conversion from 'uniqueidentifier' to 'int' is not supported on the connected database server

Tags: sql-server, uniqueidentifier, ssms

I'm about to migrate my database from using old membership to the one included in mvc4, which uses `int` instead of `guid`.

When changing the type I get following error:

> *Conversion from int to uniqueidentifier is not supported on the connected database server.*

How can I change `UserId` to `int` via SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: Those datatypes are not compatible, you'll need to convert them using a calculation that works for you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to add a new column ( `ALTER TABLE ADD [NewId] INTEGER` ) then run the following to populate the new id column :

```
WITH Cte
AS
(
    SELECT *
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Your GUID Column Here] DESC) AS RowNumber
    FROM YourTable
)
UPDATE Cte
SET [NewId]= RowNumber
GO
```

There you have a new ID column that you can use a clustered primary key

Answer (score 79):

First Change Data Type to any other supported Type like varbinary or anything. then you can convert from that to what you want.

Comment: Sometimes **save** operation after change to another type is needed; in the other hand will not work.

Comment: It is working also for from 'int' to 'uniqueidentifier'

Comment: Worth pointing out that indexes may be deleted from the column whose type is being changed.

Answer (score 2):

With reference to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/d7d0h4wt(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) post:

Deleting the current column and adding a new column with the required data type should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

as we know;
the unique identifier variable is 32 bytes;
int is 8 bytes and bigint is 16 bytes.

we  make convert ,first byte and after uniqueidentifier.

Simple code;

```
Select CAST( CAST(cast(0 as bigint) AS varbinary)+CAST(cast(88 as bigint) AS varbinary) as uniqueidentifier)
```